# Perl - Declared variable with 'my', still get error

Tags: perl

so I'm getting this error:

```
Global symbol "@Z" requires explicit package name 
(did you forget to declare "my @Z"?) at 
C:/Users/owner/Documents/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm line 937. Global symbol "@Z" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @Z"?) at C:/Users/owner/Documents/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm line 945
```

Code:

```
my ($X_ref,$Y_ref)=grid($min_X,$max_X,$min_Y,$max_Y,$distance);my @X=@$X_ref;my @Y=@{$Y_ref};
for my $i (0..$#X){
    $Z[$i]=20;#The function that defined the height of each point. This setting wil give you a flat roof. For a more advanced tree, try:
    #$Z[$i]=-0.01*$X[$i]**2+0.2*$Y[$i]-0.005*$Y[$i]**2+20;
}

#End of input parameters.

my $min_radian = deg2rad($min_angle);
my $b = tan($min_radian);
my @Z=map{$_/$b} @Z;
```

After declaring the code with "my" for each of the respected errors:

```
"my" variable @Z masks earlier declaration in same statement at C:/Users/owner/Documents/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm line 945.
"my" variable @Z masks earlier declaration in same statement at C:/Users/owner/Documents/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm line 945.
syntax error at C:/Users/owner/Documents/Slic3r/lib/Slic3r/Print/SupportMaterial.pm line 937, near "$Z["
```

Code:

```
my ($X_ref,$Y_ref)=grid($min_X,$max_X,$min_Y,$max_Y,$distance);my @X=@$X_ref;my @Y=@{$Y_ref};
for my $i (0..$#X){
    my $Z[$i]=20;#The function that defined the height of each point. This setting wil give you a flat roof. For a more advanced tree, try:
    #$Z[$i]=-0.01*$X[$i]**2+0.2*$Y[$i]-0.005*$Y[$i]**2+20;
}

#End of input parameters.

my $min_radian = deg2rad($min_angle);
my $b = tan($min_radian);
my @Z=map{$_/$b} my @Z;
```

Any help would be great guys, really struggling to figure why these two are not working correctly.

Comment: If `@Z` is already declared elsewhere, then why are you using `my`? On the other hand, if it's not already declared elsewhere, then why are you trying to pass an undefined variable to `map`? This is the equivalent of `int x = x;` in C.

Comment: You need to declare variables using `my` in the scope you want them to exist in visually. [This tutorial](https://github.com/mvanwinkleias/perl_tutorials/blob/master/MyOurLocalTutorial.pod) may be helpful. Your syntax error comes from `my $Z[$i]` which is an invalid declaration (and you want it declared outside that scope anyway).

Comment: @MikeHolt no, it isn't.  while my returns the new variable and allows you to do things like assign to it, otherwise the scope of a lexical in perl only begins on the following statement.  so `my @Z = 1..3; my @Z = map 4-$_, @Z; print @Z` prints 432; the second @Z in the second statement is the first one declared, not the second.

Comment: @ysth I was talking about the case when there is no previously defined `@Z`, and the point was just that he was referencing a non-existent variable. I hadn't yet seen the `my @Z` declared inside the loop, but even in that case, the `@Z` inside the for loop dies once it goes out of scope. If you have `use strict` on, and you attempted to reference `@Z` after the loop, it would complain about `@Z` being undeclared. And without `use strict`, if you did `my @Z { whatever } @Z` after the loop, you'd just get an auto-vivified `@Z`, not the same `@Z` from inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring `@Z` (using the keyword `my`) in two different scopes. One inside the `for` loop, and one afterwards. If you need `@Z` to still exist after the `for` loop completes, you need to declare it outside of (and prior to) that scope.

Also, only use `my` once:

```
my @Z;
my ($X_ref,$Y_ref)=grid($min_X,$max_X,$min_Y,$max_Y,$distance);my @X=@$X_ref;my @Y=@{$Y_ref};
for my $i (0..$#X){
    $Z[$i]=20;#The function that defined the height of each point. This setting      wil give you a flat roof. For a more advanced tree, try:
    #$Z[$i]=-0.01*$X[$i]**2+0.2*$Y[$i]-0.005*$Y[$i]**2+20;
}

#End of input parameters.

my $min_radian = deg2rad($min_angle);
my $b = tan($min_radian);
@Z=map{$_/$b} @Z;
```

Answer (score -2):

When you set my, so you have to define the base.

old school: my @Z =(); 
new school: my $Z ="";

This should be the missed one.

Comment: Sorry but this answer makes no sense.